# LibGDX Rotate 2D image with touchDragged() event

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

**Objective: to rotate an image in the center of the screen with movement equal to left or right touchDragged event.**

Right now I have a basic Stage that is created and adds an actor (centerMass.png) to the stage. it is created and rendered like this:

```
public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter {
Stage stageGamePlay;

@Override
public void create () {
    //setup game stage variables
    stageGamePlay = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    stageGamePlay.addActor(new CenterMass(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("centerMass.png"))));

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stageGamePlay);

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255f/255, 249f/255, 236f/255, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //before drawing, updating actions that have changed
    stageGamePlay.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stageGamePlay.draw();

    }
}
```

I then have a separate class file that contains the CenterMass class, extending Image. I am familiar enough to know I could extend Actor, but I am not sure the benefit I would gain using Actor vs Image.

In the CenterMass class I create the texture, set bounds, set touchable and center it on the screen.

Inside CenterMass class I also have an InputListener listening for events. I have an override set for touchDragged where I am trying to get the X and Y of the drag, and use that to set the rotate actions accordingly. That class looks like this:

```
//extend Image vs Actor classes
public class CenterMass extends Image {
public CenterMass(Texture centerMassSprite) {
    //let parent be aware
    super(centerMassSprite);
    setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    setRotation(90f);


    addListener(new InputListener(){
        private int dragX, dragY;
        private float duration;
        private float rotateBy = 30f;

        @Override
        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            //get
            float dX = (float)(x-dragX)/(float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            float dY = (float)(dragY-y)/(float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

            duration = 1.0f; // 1 second

            Actions.sequence(
                    Actions.parallel(
                            Actions.rotateBy(rotateBy, duration),
                            Actions.moveBy( dX, dY, duration)
                    )
            );


        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void positionChanged() {
    //super.positionChanged();
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    //draw needs to be available for changing color and rotation, I think
    batch.setColor(this.getColor());
    //cast back to texture because we use Image vs Actor and want to rotate and change color safely
    ((TextureRegionDrawable)getDrawable()).draw(batch, getX(), getY(),
            getOriginX(), getOriginY(),
            getWidth(), getHeight(),
            getScaleX(), getScaleY(),
            getRotation());
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    }
}
```

**The Problem:**
I have not been able to get it to rotate the way I would like. I have been able to get it to shift around in unpredictable ways. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Actions.sequence()` is a convenience method to create a `SequenceAction` object. You have to give this action to your Actor for it to do anything.

```
//addAction() is a member of Actor
this.addAction(Actions.sequence(...))
```

However, this is probably not what you want. Firstly, a `SequenceAction` is an action where it waits for each action to finish before the next action is applied. To execute both at the same time, you don't need the `sequence()` or `parallel()` calls, just

```
this.addAction(Actions.rotateBy(rotateBy, duration));
this.addAction(Actions.moveBy( dX, dY, duration));
```

They will execute in parallel and remove themselves when they have finished after `duration` seconds.

That being said, you might not want to use actions in the first place As your code is now, you will add `Action`s to the image actor each time that the `touchDragged()` event fires, regardless of whether the prior `Action`s have completed. You could wait until the `Action`s are finished (via `Actor.hasAction()`) or clear the existing `Action`s from the `Actor` before re-adding them. Or you could forgo adding any `Action`s at all and have your `touchDragged()` event directly move and rotate the image.

P.S. There really is no reason at this point to inherit from `Actor` since `Image` already inherits from `Actor`